# Whether to deploy a web Service within the esb or outside the esb

Tags: java, web-services, soa, esb

I am working on building a web service(s) that is rest based (some may be soap based) and that will be invoked by external agents.
Agents being any software outside of our network.

I am considering two options

i) run the web service on a container outside of esb and expose a jetty endpoint from the fuse esb for the outside world.

ii) run the webservice within the esb container.

I am wondering what are the pros and cons of deploying the web service within the ESB or outside of the esb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is specific to Fuse ESB. Fuse containers are capable of hosting the mediation routes as well as the web services itself. 
If you are developing the web services based on OSGI, you may as well deploy the services on Fuse containers.

If the load is not high, the routes and the web service(s) could be hosted on the same physical container. In all cases, it is ideal to have separate bundles for the routes and the web services. The part exposed for integration becomes the ESB part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of a business solution of deploying a webservice withing an `ESB`.

`ESB` is usually used as **Mediator** that implements various **non-functional properties** (security, mediation, transformation).

`ESB` can fulfill some **functional properties** (e.g. message enrichment) but implementing the businesses logic fully within the `ESB` sounds like unnecessary coupling of the `ESB` and `Webservice Application Server` roles. The two roles should be separated to maximize benefits of both.